# To get the complete row with join tables in Zend_Db_Table

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

This is my table structure.

http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/8730/articlek.jpg

I want to get a article row object from id with section and category names instead of section_id and category_id ,And user names instead of author_id and modified_by.

Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `Zend_Db_Table`'s `setIntegrityCheck()` functionality:

Something like this should work:

```
$articleTable = new Article();
$select = $articleTable->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from('article', 'article.*');
$select->joinLeft('user', 'article.author_id = user.id', array('author_name'=>'author'));
$select->where('article.id = 123');
$articleRecord = $articleTable->fetchRow($select);
```

You can check the SQL generated using:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($select->__toString());
```

Note that the returned `Zend_Db_Table_Row` object is read only.

Comment: Shouldn't it be:

$select = $articleTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);

(according to the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.advanced.usage).

Comment: Yes, you need the setIntegrityCheck(false); Thanks!

I've updated the code so that it's not misleading :)

Comment: I created a class(ArticleRow) by extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract and in it's init() method I wrote the query(can see in 0 answer).But I have no idea how to get the data I wanted from Controller.I'll very grateful if anyone can give a tip for me.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is outside of the scope of Zend_Db_Table. Zend_Db_Table can make it easy to get those other rows ([see here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html)) but it won't do it for automatically. You may want to check out the [Zend Framework Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart), it talks about using the DataMapper pattern and that might be something you want to look into.

One option you do have to extend Zend_Db_Table_Row and in the init() method query the other tables for the information you need. You can specify a row class to use in your Zend_Db_Table class by overriding the rowClass variable:

```
protected $_rowClass = 'FooRow';
```

From comments:

```
require_once(dirname(realpath(__FILE__) . '/path/relative/to/articles/ArticleRow.php');
```

Comment: I already set dependentTables and referenceMaps for tables.But I don't know how to get the appropriate result I want from Zend_Db_Table(article table).

Thanks for helping

Comment: This is it's sql code.

select sec.title as 'section',
       cat.title as 'category',
       auth.Name as 'author',
 modi.Name as 'modifier',
 art.*
  from article art
         left outer join
       section      sec on sec.id = art.section_id
         left outer join
       category      cat on cat.id = art.category_id
         left outer join
       user      auth on auth.id = art.author_id
left outer join
       user      modi on modi.id = art.modified_by
where art.id='1'

Comment: I updated my answer with a potential solution. I really feel like though if need this kind of functionality then Zend_Db_Table is the wrong direction.

Comment: This is the simplest sql code for it.

SELECT article. * , section.title, category.title, user.name, u2.name
FROM article
INNER JOIN section ON article.section_id = section.id
INNER JOIN category ON article.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN user ON article.author_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON article.modified_by = u2.id
WHERE article.id = '1'

If I create a class extending Zend_Db_Table_Row in init(),I can not understand about protected $_rowClass = 'FooRow';.

your information is very helpful for me.If you can give a link for tutorial it will be vey helpful for me.Thanks again

Comment: If I create a class extending Zend_Db_Table_Row in init(),I can not understand about protected $_rowClass = 'FooRow';. your information is very helpful for me.If you can give a link for tutorial it will be vey helpful for me.Thanks again

Comment: Here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.extending is an explanation of how to create your own Zend_Db_Table_Row class.

Comment: I created a class(ArticleRow) by extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract and in it's init() method I wrote the query.It will return the joined row object.
And also I added "protected $_rowClass = 'ArticleRow';" to Article Zend_Db_Table class.But Zend_Loader doesn't load the "ArticleRow".I added my "ArticleRow" class as an answer(for this question) because in comments the code will be collapsed.Am I code wrong way?

Comment: Is your models folder in your include path? If not, you can just require_once the ArticleRow class in your Articles class.

Comment: I add "require_once 'ArticleRow.php';".But it give the same result.If file not found It must be give a "failed to open stream" warning.I only add "protected $_rowClass = 'ArticleRow';" to Article class.Do I want to add anything else for ArticleRow class.Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Is ArticleRow.php in the same folder as Articles.php? Use the absolute path to the file if need be. (See above)

Comment: I add "require_once(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/ArticleRow.php'));".But same result.Thanks in deep.

Comment: It's work,the case was I used autoloader for load views,models,layout & etc.For that I must use App_Model_ prefix for load default models,So I would use "protected $_rowClass = 'App_Model_ArticleRow';" in my Article class.Thank you very much in deeeeeeeeeep.I'm really new for zend.Thank you very much again.And also this give worning because in Article_Row, I want to get article details of specifc article(by passing argument of article id).But in here,give worning "Missing argument 1 for App_Model_ArticleRow::init()".So how do I want to pass the article_id for get details of a specific article.

Comment: Thank you very much in deep.Zend_Db_Table_Row is really new for me,Thanks again.